# Convert a mixed nested dictionary into a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list like this:

```
d1=  {'Hiraki': {'Hiraki_2': ['KANG_751']}, 'LakeTaupo': {'LakeTaupo_4': ['KANG_708', 'KANG_785'], 'LakeTaupo_6': ['KANG_785'], 'LakeTaupo_2': ['KANG_751', 'KANG_785', 'KANG_785', 'KANG_785'], 'LakeTaupo_3': ['KANG_669', 'KANG_669', 'KANG_708', 'KANG_708', 'KANG_669']}}
```

I would like to convert this nested list into a nested list, like:

```
d2= ['Hiraki': ['Hiraki_2': ['KANG_751']], 'LakeTaupo': ['LakeTaupo_4': ['KANG_708', 'KANG_785'], 'LakeTaupo_6': ['KANG_785'], 'LakeTaupo_2': ['KANG_751', 'KANG_785', 'KANG_785', 'KANG_785'], 'LakeTaupo_3': ['KANG_669', 'KANG_669', 'KANG_708', 'KANG_708', 'KANG_669']]]
```

My below python code does not convert the dictionary fully into a list:

```
list_key_value = [ [k,v] for k, v in d1.items() ]
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your `d1` is a dict, not a list, and that the "nested list" you give as your desired output is not actually valid syntax.  A dictionary and a list are not the same thing.

That said, here's how to do the conversion you're attempting in such a way as to handle arbitrarily deep nested dictionaries:

```
>>> def dict_to_list(d: dict) -> list:
...     if isinstance(d, list):
...         return d
...     if isinstance(d, dict):
...         return [[k, dict_to_list(v)] for k, v in d.items()]
...     return [d]
...
>>> d1=  {'Hiraki': {'Hiraki_2': ['KANG_751']}, 'LakeTaupo': {'LakeTaupo_4': ['KANG_708', 'KANG_785'], 'LakeTaupo_6': ['KANG_785'], 'LakeTaupo_2': ['KANG_751', 'KANG_785', 'KANG_785', 'KANG_785'], 'LakeTaupo_3': ['KANG_669', 'KANG_669', 'KANG_708', 'KANG_708', 'KANG_669']}}
>>> dict_to_list(d1)
[['Hiraki', [['Hiraki_2', ['KANG_751']]]], ['LakeTaupo', [['LakeTaupo_4', ['KANG_708', 'KANG_785']], ['LakeTaupo_6', ['KANG_785']], ['LakeTaupo_2', ['KANG_751', 'KANG_785', 'KANG_785', 'KANG_785']], ['LakeTaupo_3', ['KANG_669', 'KANG_669', 'KANG_708', 'KANG_708', 'KANG_669']]]]]
```