# Remove the duplicate value in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary d1

```
d1={'Hiraki': {'Hiraki_2': ['KANG_785','KANG_785','KANG_762']}, 'LakeTaupo': {'LakeTaupo_2': ['KANG_785', 'KANG_785', 'KANG_785', 'KANG_751']}}
```

I would like to remove the duplicate values for each key. The result after removing the duplicate values should be:

```
d1={'Hiraki': {'Hiraki_2': ['KANG_785','KANG_762']}, 'LakeTaupo': {'LakeTaupo_2': ['KANG_785', 'KANG_751']}}
```

I do not how to code it in python. Please help me.

Comment: what you have tries?

Comment: Is it always a 2 level dictionary...

Comment: Do you know how to remove duplicates from a list in general? If you can do that, you simply loop over the dictionary entries and assign the result back to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you want to remove duplicate values in a `sequence`, you convert it to a `set` then back again.

```py
>>> data = ['KANG_785','KANG_785','KANG_762']
>>> data = list(set(data))
>>> data
['KANG_762', 'KANG_785']
```

Notice that this will not maintain ordering.

Also, consider carefully if you actually need a `list` or not; a `set` is still iterable after all, so if you want to maintain uniqueness at all time, consider storing the data as a `set` and convert to `list` only when necessary.

```py
>>> data = ['KANG_785','KANG_785','KANG_762']
>>> data = set(data)
>>> data
{'KANG_762', 'KANG_785'}
>>> for i in data:
...     print(i)
...     
KANG_762
KANG_785
>>> type(data)
<class 'set'>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same strategy as described in this answer:

[Convert a mixed nested dictionary into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62442612/convert-a-mixed-nested-dictionary-into-a-list/62442695#62442695)

but for the case where `isinstance(d, list)`, return `list(set(d))` (which will remove duplicate entries) instead of `d`.

E.g.:

```
def dedupe_lists(d: dict) -> dict:
    if isinstance(d, list):
        return list(set(d))
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return {k: dedupe_lists(v) for k, v in d.items()}
    return d
```

Comment: Very neat! - recursion is an art.

Comment: What is ``- > dict `` ?

Comment: A type annotation clarifying that this function returns a dict -- which is actually a lie in the recursive calls, but as I was sorting it out I was trying to keep track of the fact that the original caller is going to pass in a dict and expect to get a dict back with roughly the same shape.  A better type annotation would take a tricky `Union` type.

Comment: Thanks so much for your great help Samwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
d1={'Hiraki': {'Hiraki_2': ['KANG_785','KANG_785','KANG_762']}, 'LakeTaupo': {'LakeTaupo_2': ['KANG_785', 'KANG_785', 'KANG_785', 'KANG_751']}}

output = {}
for key, val in d1.items():
    for key1, val1 in val.items():
        output[key] = {
            key1: list(set(val1))
        }
print(output)
```

Output:

```
{'Hiraki': {'Hiraki_2': ['KANG_785', 'KANG_762']}, 'LakeTaupo': {'LakeTaupo_2': ['KANG_785', 'KANG_751']}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use set() to eliminate duplicates.

```
d1={'Hiraki': {'Hiraki_2': ['KANG_785','KANG_785','KANG_762']}, 'LakeTaupo': {'LakeTaupo_2': ['KANG_785', 'KANG_785', 'KANG_785', 'KANG_751']}}

d2 ={key1: {key2: list(set(val2)) for key2, val2 in val1.items()} for key1, val1 in 
d1.items()}

print(d2)
```

Output:

```
{'Hiraki': {'Hiraki_2': ['KANG_785', 'KANG_762']}, 'LakeTaupo': {'LakeTaupo_2': ['KANG_785', 'KANG_751']}}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Here is a recursive solution:

This will change the lists *inplace*

```py
d1={'Hiraki': {'Hiraki_2': ['KANG_785','KANG_785','KANG_762']}, 'LakeTaupo': {'LakeTaupo_2': ['KANG_785', 'KANG_785', 'KANG_785', 'KANG_751']}}

# Deals with the tuples
def recurse_tuple(my_tup):
    for i, v in enumerate(my_tup):
        if isinstance(v, dict): my_tup[i] = recurse_dict(v)
    return my_tup

# Deals with the dictionaries and lists
def recurse_dict(my_dict):
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict): my_dict[k] = recurse_dict(v)
        if isinstance(v, tuple): my_dict[k] = recurse_tuple(v)
        if isinstance(v, list): my_dict[k] = set(v)
    return my_dict

print(recurse_dict(d1))

#Output
{'Hiraki': {'Hiraki_2': {'KANG_762', 'KANG_785'}}, 'LakeTaupo': {'LakeTaupo_2': {'KANG_785', 'KANG_751'}}}
```

NOTE: @Samwise has beaten me to the punch with a very neat recursive function.